# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment using quadmath and random number generator

Tags: c++, random

I am compiling a C++ code to run a DFT. I am using quadmath in my code and a random number generator to add noise to it. 
While running the code as:

```
g++ code.cc -lquadmath -o quad
```

I get no error and its successfully compiles, 
But owing to usage of random number generator, I have to compile as

```
g++ code.cc -lquadmath -std=gnu++0x -o quad
```

which gives an error lvaule required as left operand of assignment.
The code line that throw this error is:

```
std::real(output_seq[y]) =std::real(output_seq[y])+( V2[x] * cosineA );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to the result of `std::real` which is a [rvalue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx) .

That makes as much sense as writing

```
5.0f = std::real(output_seq[y]) + (V2[x] * cosineA);
```

So you probably want to do this instead

```
output_seq[y] = std::real(output_seq[y]) + (V2[x] * cosineA);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a value to a number. `std::real(output_seq[y])` returns the real part of your complex number as a value. You cannot assign it a new value as it does not represent an address location.

What you want to do is probably the following:

```c++
output_seq[y].real(std::real(output_seq[y])+( V2[x] * cosineA ));
```

It will only work with C++11 using the following the information http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/real/